# Finding the minimum number of characters needed to display multiple phrases

Tags: c++

Let's say we have a list of different multi-letter phrases that we want to display **one at a time** on a wall.

Each letter must be purchased separately, so we want to know the **minimum number of characters** and which **characters we need to buy** to be able to display each of the phrases.

For example: *To display phrases "**Computer**" and "**Visual studio community**" we would need:*

- *c, o, m, p, u, t, e, r, v, i, s, a, l, s, u, d, i, o, m, u, n, i, t, y.*
- *24 Characters.*

The output `c, o, m, p, u, t, e, r, v, i, s, a, l, s, u, d, i, o, m, u, n, i, t, y` contains the minimum number of characters required to form the phrases ***computer*** and ***visual studio community*** so what the program should do is print the first phrase as it is because it already contains the minimum amount of characters needed to display that phrase and use the letters from the first phrase to display the second phrase. Now to display `Visual studio community` we would need these extra letters `v, i, s, a, l, s, u, d, i, o, m, u, n, i, t, y` because we can re-use the letter `u` from ***computer*** to form `visual`, same with the letter `t`, we can take that from ***computer*** to from `studio`.

If I add to the input the word `Computer`, the output should not change as the word can be formed with the letters that are in that vector without the need of extra letters or if I add an extra `t` to `studio` and make it `visual sttudio community` for the input, the output should contain an extra `t` because there's one `t` from `computer` and it needs another one which it prints out to the output.

If the question I started this post with is still unclear I will try to explain it differently with more examples. It was part of an interview and that is everything that was given to me.

Here's the program I wrote for it and I would like to know if there's a simpler way of doing it, also the speed is not a concern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> phrases = {/*0*/ "Hello world", /*1*/ "Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet", /*2*/ "This is a programming challenge"};

    vector<char> letters;

    for (int i = 0; i < phrases.size(); i++)
    {
        string copyOfPhrases = phrases[i];
        vector<char> copyOfLetters = letters;

        copyOfPhrases.erase(remove(copyOfPhrases.begin(), copyOfPhrases.end(), ' '), copyOfPhrases.end());
        transform(copyOfPhrases.begin(), copyOfPhrases.end(), copyOfPhrases.begin(), ::tolower);

                for (int j = 0; j < copyOfPhrases.size(); j++)
        {

            int ok = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < copyOfLetters.size(); k++)
            {
                if (copyOfPhrases[j] == copyOfLetters[k])
                {
                    ok += 1;
                }
            }
            if (ok == 0)
            {
                letters.push_back(copyOfPhrases[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                copyOfLetters.erase(find(copyOfLetters.begin(), copyOfLetters.end(), copyOfPhrases[j]));
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << letters[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl
         << letters.size();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the rules? Why do you need two `m`?

Comment: If ther are to be no duplicates, throw all of the characters into one `vector`, sort the `vector`, run the `vector` through [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique), finally return the distance from the start of the vector to the iterator returned by `std::unique`.

Comment: Or use a [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) and return the [size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/size)

Comment: That's good point. `unordered_set`s certainly easier. Not sure if it's faster, or if speed's even a concern here. I'd start with simpler.

Comment: @user4581301 The hash set (O(n)) should be faster than a vector sort (O(n log(n)))

Comment: We've missed whether or not case matters.  If the character set is limited, a dumb array of `bool`s may have both beaten.

Comment: The thing with the vector sort is we do it once. The insert look-up is done every time we insert another character.

Comment: @user4581301 But all of these approaches won't return the expected result 24.

Comment: Because of the magical mystery m?

Comment: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fdb355d9ae5f20e ?

Comment: @user4581301 It's not only the `m`. The expected result contains three `u`. I don't see any pattern.

Comment: No pattern suggests close the question until it can be clarified.

Comment: You could make better use of the stanndard library. ..  code at https://godbolt.org/z/n5rbfE6dv

Comment: @ThomasSablik I tried to clarify that extra `m` for you by editing the post, if you think you still need clarification after reading it please reply to this comment and I will try to explain it differently.

Comment: Focusing on the Ms we have one m in co**m**puter and two ms in Visual studio co**mm**unity. We share 1 m for both words, but still need the second m, for community, yes?

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Groovy. Definitely answerable now.

Comment: Count the letters in each phrase. Iterate over all phrases and take the maximum number for each letter. `c: 1, o: 1, m: 1, p: 1, u: 1, t: 1, e: 1, r: 1` and `v: 1, i: 3, s: 2, u: 3, a: 1, l: 1, t: 2, d: 1, o: 2, m: 2, n: 1, y: 1` yields `c: 1, p: 1 e: 1, r: 1, v: 1, i: 3, s: 2, u: 3, a: 1, l: 1, t: 2, d: 1, o: 2, m: 2, n: 1, y: 1`

Comment: @ThomasSablik I actually thought about that and even though it's simpler, I would need to print the letters one by one in the order of their appearance but still I could work with that and see what I can come up with that would satisfy the criteria.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Yep, that does the job perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If that's what you meant, there are indeed functions in the standard library that can help.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    static const std::vector<std::string> phrases = { "Computer",  "Visual studio community" };
    std::vector<char> letters;

    for (int i = 0; i < phrases.size(); i++)
    {
        std::string s = phrases[i];

        // remove spaces.
        s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), ' '), s.end());

        // to lower case
        std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), ::tolower);

        // remove letters we've already bought.
        for (size_t i = 0; i < letters.size(); ++i)
        {
            size_t pos = s.find(letters[i]);
            if (pos != std::string::npos)
                s.erase(pos, 1);
        }
        
        // buy what's left.
        letters.insert(letters.end(), s.begin(), s.end());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < letters.size(); i++)
        std::cout << letters[i] << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl << letters.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your code produces 17 (only one `m` and one `u`) for the phrases `Computer` and `Visual studio community`, but the expected result is 24 (with two `m` and three `u`).

Comment: @ThomasSablik  After checking by hand, 17 is indeed the cotrec t answer.  The phrases can indeed be constructed from the character array (or set) that is printed.

Comment: @ThomasSablik  This is the cotrected code referred to in the comments to the question